# How to can change the format of date from year-month-date to date-month-year in Django Admin interface?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-settings

Am new in Django so any help will be appreciated,
I have a model that contain 3 fields , one of them is date , i want to change the display of date in Django Admin(now it's **2022-05-20** but i want it to be **20-05-2022**).

How i can do that please !

this is my **models.py:**

```
class reports(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Project name", max_length=60)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date", default=date.today)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

and this is my **admin.py**:

```
class reportsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @admin.display(description='date')
    def admin_date(self, obj):
        return obj.date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

    list_display = ('user', 'project_name', 'admin_date')
admin.site.register(reports, reportsAdmin)
```

and in my **settings.py:**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True
```

but nothing work , still display to me in format **2022-05-20**(year-month-date).

How i can correctly change the format  date to be **date-month-year** in Django admin???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ss7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does convert the date to the format you want in the list page where all the reports are displayed. I don't think that what you want can be accomplished with the `reportsAdmin` class. What you need is to change the input element that can maybe be done by changing the admin templates. <del>But I am not sure that it can be done at all because that is how the input works for dates.</del>

Edit: I found this question that 3rd and 2nd answers mention some ways you can accomplish this in HTML
[Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: @avata, Yes My goal is to change the format of the input element